# How to simplify subqueries in cases with variables or other techniques - MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery, case

I am still learning SQL, and I have spent several hours searching for the answer to my question but to no avail.  If this is a dupe, please point me in the right direction!

I am building a report from data generated by a workflow tool. Here is what I need as my result:

```
| ID | Name | Company | Contract  |
| 1  | John | Acme    | Freelance |
| 2  | Bill | Acme    | Interne   |
| 3  | Mike | Duff    | Salaried  |
```

Here is the main instance table "Instance_Table":

```
| ID | Status | Date       |
| 1  | OK     | 2016-10-21 |
| 2  | Failed | 2016-10-24 |
| 3  | OK     | 2016-10-25 |
```

This is where the data is "Data_Table":

```
| DataID | InstanceID | VariableID | Value      |
| 1000   | 1          | 453        | John       |
| 1001   | 1          | 879        | Acme       |
| 1002   | 1          | 1879       | Freelance  |
| 1003   | 1          | 98         | NULL       |
| 1010   | 2          | 453        | Bill       |
| 1011   | 2          | 879        | Acme       |
| 1012   | 2          | 1879       | NULL       |
| 1013   | 2          | 98         | INT        |
| 1020   | 3          | 453        | Mike       |
| 1021   | 3          | 879        | Duff       |
| 1022   | 3          | 1879       | Salaried   |
| 1023   | 3          | 98         | SAL        |
```

As you can see there are 2 possible variables for contract, 1879 and 98.  Depending on the instance, only one or both are populated, and 98 uses a short code rather than the full word.

Here is the painful way that I get my result:

```
SELECT IT.ID,

(SELECT DT.value FROM Data_Table DT
 WHERE DT.VariableID = 453 AND IT.ID = DT.InstanceID) as "Name",

(SELECT DT.value FROM Data_Table DT
 WHERE DT.VariableID = 879 AND IT.ID = DT.InstanceID) as "Company",

CASE
 WHEN (SELECT DT.value FROM Data_Table DT
       WHERE DT.VariableID = 1897 AND IT.ID = DT.InstanceID) is NOT NULL
  THEN (SELECT DT.value FROM Data_Table DT
       WHERE DT.VariableID = 1897 AND IT.ID = DT.InstanceID)
  ELSE CASE
        WHEN (SELECT DT.value FROM Data_Table DT
              WHERE DT.VariableID = 98 AND IT.ID = DT.InstanceID) = 'SAL'
         THEN 'Salaried'
        WHEN (SELECT DT.value FROM Data_Table DT
              WHERE DT.VariableID = 98 AND IT.ID = DT.InstanceID) = 'INT'
         THEN 'Intern'
        WHEN (SELECT DT.value FROM Data_Table DT
              WHERE DT.VariableID = 98 AND IT.ID = DT.InstanceID) = 'FRE'
         THEN 'Freelance'
        ELSE '-'
      END
 END as "Contract"

FROM Instance_Table IT
```

I am asking how to simplify the repetition of each subquery using variables or another approach, as I can imagine that there is a huge performance hit to query the same table multiple times.

This example is of course a very simplified version of what I am actually doing... I have around 30 columns to put into my report and the data comes in all forms, there are nearly 70 subquery instances, as many of them are repeated. The query is very long to run and any help getting it to run faster would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "As you can see there are 2 possible variables for contract, 1879 and 98."  Actually I don't see that at all. I can't follow this at all. Can you please reword to be more clear about what you mean?  What are you talking about? I literally don't see ANY data relationship between the two tables that allows you to derive the results you want deterministically. You haven't given us all the necessary information.

Comment: Can you fix your data structure? Having a data table like that is something you will never be able to query easily or in a performant way. IF you truly cannot define the actual fields you want (only true less that 1% of the time in my experience) then use a nosql database which is optimized for this type of non-relational querying.

Comment: @pmbAustin I thought it was clear, sorry.  If you look at each InstanceID in the Data_Table you will see that the variables 1897 and 98 change (sometimes NULL, sometimes a code, and sometimes the full name of the contract). The variables 483 and 879 however always give constant data in the same way.  However I definitely can get the date I want with the query I have made.

Comment: @HLGEM Nope, I have no control over the data structure.  The workflow system is built like this out of the box unfortunately.

Comment: I still have no idea what 'logic' you're applying in order to take tables 2 and 3 and yield table 1. it looks utterly arbitrary with no rules you've identified and no rules I can come up with to make such a translation. Your question is still thoroughly unclear and there's not even remotely enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: @pmbAustin Sorry but you are over reacting.  2 out of the 3 solutions below worked, and these people didn't have trouble understanding without any other input from me.  I think you need to look into the way that different applications store data, this kind of structure is not that uncommon.  And taking a look again at the way I formed the question, the example tables make it relatively easy to understand.

Comment: @alteredNate I'm not actually. Your wording is very ambiguous. Here's what you said: "As you can see there are 2 possible variables for contract, 1879 and 98."  This says that something called 'contract' can have two variables, 1879 and 98. Maybe you didn't want the comma. I look around for something called 'contract' and instantly see three values there. Also, you never provided ANY mapping for Variable_Id. The goal of asking a question is to provide as much relevant information as possible. This question fails that test. I'm glad others could spend time puzzling it out, but don't expect that

Comment: @pmbAustin Please stop wasting my time. Thank you to those that helped, and to those that didn't want to, thank you for saying nothing.

Comment: @alteredNate I'm not wasting your time. I'm helping you to not waste other people's time (like mine) in the future by making your questions more accurate and with all necessary info. Either accept the constructive criticism or don't, but stop whining.

Comment: @pmbAustin You really want to get into this?  Do you really have nothing more substantial to do? You want to nit pick about one comma in my question?  I have gotten the help I needed from other people that were able to understand my question.  You weren't, **get over it**.  I will flag further comments from you in this thread. Go spend your time doing something that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
SELECT IT.id,
       DT_Name.value AS NAME,
       DT_Cmpy.value AS Company,
       [Contract]=CASE
                    WHEN DT_Cont_1.value IS NOT NULL THEN DT_Cont_1.value
                    ELSE
                      CASE DT_Cont_2.value
                        WHEN 'SAL' THEN 'Salaried'
                        WHEN 'INT' THEN 'Intern'
                        WHEN 'FRE' THEN 'Freelance'
                        ELSE '-'
                      END
                  END
FROM   instance_table IT
       LEFT JOIN data_table DT_Name
              ON DT_Name.variableid = 453
                 AND IT.id = DT_Name.instanceid
       LEFT JOIN data_table DT_Cmpy
              ON DT_Cmpy.variableid = 879
                 AND IT.id = DT_Cmpy.instanceid
       LEFT JOIN data_table DT_Cont_1
              ON DT_Cont_1.variableid = 1897
                 AND IT.id = DT_Cont_1.instanceid
       LEFT JOIN data_table DT_Cont_2
              ON DT_Cont_2.variableid = 98
                 AND IT.id = DT_Cont_2.instanceid
```

Comment: You could also use two joins and a group by -- might be better in his case if he has 30 more columns.

Comment: also COALESCE is probably better than the outer CASE statement.

Comment: @Hogan Myeah a bit shorter with COALESCE, but expands to the same construct. ISNULL on SQL Server is usually preferred.

Comment: Some systems are optimized to COALESCE over CASE (DB2 is one I've seen).

Comment: Great comments, thanks.  I will try these out and let you know.

Comment: @alteredNate YQW. FYI, `COALESCE(X,Y)` expands to `CASE WHEN X IS NOT NULL THEN X ELSE Y END`. The way I wrote things, has the expanded construct. In SQL Server, both are equivalent. You will see that expression X can be evaluated **twice** if expression X is not null (ANSI-SQL standard definition defines COALESCE that way). In SQL Server there is also the function `ISNULL(X,Y)`. This is nearly identical,  except for two things: **(1)** X is only ever evaluated once, and **(2)** the result of the function for a certain X and Y will only be evaluated once.

Comment: @alteredNate Meaning, that if you have `ISNULL(X,Y)` appearing twice in your query, it will only be calculated once and the result will be used wherever the expression appears. Therefore, it is usually preferred to use `ISNULL(X,Y)` instead of `COALESCE(X,Y)`.

Comment: Great info, I am trying out both now to see what works best.  But already the left joins seem to be "cleaner" for me.  I was used to using joins to pull data from multiple tables, but not to pull different data from the same table.

Comment: Why do you think that COALESCE would operate differently than ISNULL?  Standard compiler construction would have them both optimize the same way.  These aren't recursive descent parsers.

Comment: @Hogan Because the documentation sais so... From [COALESCE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx#Anchor_4): *the COALESCE expression is a syntactic shortcut for the CASE expression.*. In `CASE WHEN X IS NOT NULL THEN X ELSE Y` the expression X is evaluated twice if it is not null, and it should according to SQL.That is a known side-effect of COALESCE and the reason SQL Server has the ISNULL function. (Deterministic) SQL Server function expressions for the same parameters are only evaluated once, even if it appears more than once in an SQL expression.

Comment: @Hogan Oh forgot to mention that in `ISNULL(X,Y)`, expression X will only be evaluated once.

Comment: @TT. - ok.  There is nothing about being the same as CASE that stops it from being optimized IMO.  But that's ok, MS is always good at compatibility issues -- this just seems like one that only gets better to me.  I can't imagine a case where you want the side effect of multiple evaluations.  Probably is one.

Comment: @Hogan There probably isn't any you would want indeed. If you want a more "official" source of what I just said about side effects, read this: [COALESCE vs. ISNULL](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull), topic for *"Used with Subqueries"*.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was pulled off this project temporarily.  I have tested and it does seem like the lengthy multiple join solution does clean up a bit my code.  I do have to say however that I don't see any performance difference, in fact I nearly think that this is a tad slower.  But it's cleaner and easier to organize and edit.  Thanks!

Comment: @alteredNate You could compare the execution plans to see if there's a difference that would cause the query to execute slower. There are a lot of factors that can slow down or speed up a query, like warm vs cold cache, statistics being up to date or not, index fragmentation, number of concurrent requests on the server etc. Comparing the execution plans is usually the best way to compare efficiency. Also, make sure you have proper indexes defined on `data_table.variableid, data_table.instanceid` to speek up lookup.

Comment: @alteredNate One possible other reason for the delay is that you have subqueries in your original query that are only executed in specific conditions, while the version I posted will always do a lookup in `data_table` for all possible paths in the `CASE` expression. Again, the execution plan should tell you whether that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

use `LEFT JOIN` instead of correlated sub-queries

```
SELECT IT.ID,
       DT1.value                AS "Name",
       DT2.value                AS "Company",
       COALESCE(DT3.value, CASE DT4.value
                             WHEN 'SAL' THEN 'Salaried'
                             WHEN 'INT' THEN 'Intern'
                             WHEN 'FRE' THEN 'Freelance'
                             ELSE '-'
                           END) AS "Contract"
FROM   Instance_Table IT
       LEFT JOIN Data_Table DT1
              ON IT.ID = DT1.InstanceID
                 AND DT1.VariableID = 453
       LEFT JOIN Data_Table DT2
              ON IT.ID = DT2.InstanceID
                 AND DT2.VariableID = 879
       LEFT JOIN Data_Table DT3
              ON IT.ID = DT3.InstanceID
                 AND DT3.VariableID = 1897
       LEFT JOIN Data_Table DT4
              ON IT.ID = DT4.InstanceID
                 AND DT4.VariableID = 98
                 AND DT.value IN ( 'SAL', 'INT', 'FRE' )
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to look more into COALESCE to understand it better.  I think I understand the LEFT JOIN principal in this case, I need to have an instance of a join for every unique variable number.  One way or another this is a complex query.  I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this without multiple joins to data_table.

```
SELECT 
    it.ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DT.VariableID = 453 THEN DT.VALUE END) AS "Name",
    MAX(CASE WHEN DT.VariableID = 879 THEN DT.VALUE END) AS "Company",
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN DT.VariableID = 1897 THEN DT.VALUE END), 
        MAX(CASE WHEN DT.VariableID = 98 AND dt.VALUE = 'SAL' THEN 'Salary' 
                 WHEN DT.VariableID = 98 AND dt.VALUE = 'INT' THEN 'Intern'
                 WHEN DT.VariableID = 98 AND dt.VALUE = 'FRE' THEN 'Freelance'
                END)
    ) AS "Contract"
FROM 
    Instance_Table it
    LEFT JOIN Data_Table dt ON  it.ID = dt.InstanceID
GROUP BY it.ID
```

Comment: I don't think your logic for Contract is right given the GROUP BY

Comment: i think it would only have an issue if the value for VariableID 1879 was different than the value for 98.. if they both match, for ex `Salary, SAL` then they should return the correct value of `Salary`.  if they can be different and VariableID 1879 supersedes 98 then the my first answer before the edit should work

Comment: I have unfortunately no control over indexes and keys.  And as I don't have any way of controlling the data in variables 98 and 1879, I don't know how this would provide constant results.  I will look into it if the solutions below don't work.  Thanks.

Comment: @Hogan i guess i'm missing your point.. If  VariableID is 1879 and Variable is null then the MAX aggregate will ignore it and get the MAX value of VariableID = 98.. is that not the way it should work?

Comment: @Hogan the edit just forces it to use whatever value is assigned to VariableID 1897 if Value IS NOT NULL.. in case VariableID 98 is different than  1897.. the other way would always pic `Salaried` if it exists for the ID, over the other values regardless of the non null value of VariableID 1897.. this just changes the priority.. if `VariableID is 1879 and Variable is null` this edit doesnt change anything

Comment: @JamieD77 -- sorry all this makes me very lost.  All I know is with the coalesce it works like the OP's question -- without that part it worked different.